# Function with multiple return statement in if clauses does not behave as expected?

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I'm not new to Java programming in any way, but this problem is unheard of to me.
I have this code:

```
private static boolean isEarlierThanAndNotReminded(Callback left, Callback right) {    
if(right == null) {
            return !left.isReminded();
        }
        else {
            return !left.isReminded() && (left.getAlertStart().before(right.getAlertStart()));
 }
}
```

Ok so the problem is that I get a report of a null pointer on the line in the "else" clause. 
When I debug, I can see that `right` is actually null, but still the execution land first in the if-clause and then control continues into the "else"-clause where it gets a null pointer. 
I am clueless to what I am missing here, any suggestions?

Comment: Go back over your old questions and accept some of the answers. This will make more people want to help you with new questions. It also helps others find questions with answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably just a function of the optimisation of the compiler and the way the debugger handles it.
It's going to the 'if' first condition but not actually executing the return. If you think about it, whatever 
the value of 'right' is the code  needs to know the value of ' !left.isReminded()', so that statement has to be executed. I bet that if you started your function with

```
boolean leftRemindedValue = left.isReminded();
```

before the if statement and then did put that new boolean into your return statements, you would see a different execution path in the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Thats a bit of a mixed up If statement, I may not have your logic right but this should make more sense to you:

```
private static boolean isEarlierThanAndNotReminded(Callback left, Callback right) {    
     if(right != null) {
        return !right.isReminded();
     } else {
        return !left.isReminded();
     }
```

}

You want to check that right isn't null, if it isn't it means you have a 'right' callback so use the right object , else you assume you have a left callback and use this.

This bit of code:

```
  && (left.getAlertStart().before(right.getAlertStart())
```

needs you to check for both left and right null checks:

```
 if(left != null && right != null){
     return (left.getAlertStart().before(right.getAlertStart());
 }
```

So if I have this right you would end up with:

```
 private static boolean isEarlierThanAndNotReminded(Callback left, Callback right) {    
     boolean returnVal = false;
     if(right != null) {
        returnVal = !right.isReminded();
     } else if (left != null){
        returnVal = !left.isReminded();
     }
     if(left != null && right != null){
        returnVal  = returnVal && (left.getAlertStart().before(right.getAlertStart());
     }
     return returnVal;
}
```

Comment: @Arian fixed it. Although the original poster was assuming if right was null left could never be null.

Comment: That's true, but I guess exactly that assumption was the problem.

Comment: The left.getAlertStart() was null, and the reason explained in  NickT:s answer above made it difficult to see.

Answer (score 1):

The `right` is not the only reference which can be `null` in the `else` clause. The `left.getAlertStart()` might be `null` as well -- that's likely what causes the exception.

Comment: I agree, but if "right" is null, it should never enter the else-clause.